# How to manage length of dashes

Tags: css, styles

How to manage length of dashes in CSS?
I could have added `border-width: 2px` but this makes it thicker and bigger, not longer/wider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS border dash length is browser specific and uncontrollable [(source)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-style-properties). You can however [|use border images|](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp) with the border-image option to give you full control of the border style. It is pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you cannot change the length of the dashes applied by the `border` property.